# install_failed_missing_shared_library how can i solve this issue?

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, web-applications, android-manifest

i'm trying to debug my project on Android Studio something really simple the hello world thing.
and i get this message:

"Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\Pierr\AndroidStudioProjects\Hello\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'"
""
this is my AndroidManifest.xml
""`

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"  />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`
if i put android:required="false" it will work but just crashes before we see anything.
I checked if i had the file they were looking for <app-debug.apk> and i did have it please help.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today,
I solved it by deleting this part in the manifest

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
```